# Decodable, Encodable, Glossy conformance issues using Gloss framework

Tags: ios, json, swift, serialization, swift3

I tried to use [Gloss](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss) in order to serialize and deserialize incoming and outgoing network data from and to JSON/Swift objects:

```
struct User: Decodable, Glossy {

    let id: Int?
    let username: String?

    init?(json: JSON) {
        self.id = "id" <~~ json
        self.username = "username" <~~ json
    }

    func toJSON() -> JSON? {
        return jsonify([
            "id" ~~> self.ownerId,
            "username" ~~> self.username
            ])
    }

}
```

But I got:

> Type 'User' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

and

> 'JSON' is not convertible to 'JSON'...

Anybody could help me with this issue?

Comment: as per documents use `struct User: Glossy { ... }`, remove Decodable

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: i removed Decodable, but the error remains..

Answer (score 0):

The only thing wrong with your code is the reference to `ownerId` instead of `id`. If you use `Glossy`, there's no need to specify `Gloss.Decodable` since it's a composition of both `Gloss.Decodable`, `Gloss.Encodable`:

```
import Gloss

// If you use Glossy, there's no need to use Gloss.Decodable since it's a composition of both Decodable, Encodable
struct User: Glossy {
    let id: Int?
    let username: String?

    // Gloss.Decodable
    init?(json: JSON) {
        self.id = "id" <~~ json
        self.username = "username" <~~ json
    }

    // Gloss.Encodable
    func toJSON() -> JSON? {
        return jsonify([
            "id" ~~> self.id,
            "username" ~~> self.username
        ])
    }

}
```

Tested with Swift 3.1, 3.2, 4 (Consider migrating to Swift's 4 `Codable`).

Comment: thanks for your answer.. when will be swift 4 out of beta?

Comment: could it be because of my project settings that my project does not compile correctly?

Comment: Not sure, try cleaning the project, deleting derived data and rebuilding.